# Wrong NSDate conversion from String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have date(NSDate),

I convert with format “EEEE,dd MMM YYYY” so output is.  “Monday,22 May 2017”

But when convert this string to date it give wrong date

using this code

```
 NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMM YYYY"];
  NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:“Monday,22 May 2017”];
```

Wrong output is 2016-12-25 18:30:00 +0000

anyone can help please?

Comment: date has no proper format,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date has no proper format, but in here use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`

> @"YYYY" is week-based calendar year.
>
> @"yyyy" is ordinary calendar year.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMM yyyy"];
```

for sample

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"Monday,22 May 2017"];
```

Comment: yes problem is "YYYY". but I can't figure exact time rather than original date.

Comment: @Rushi - date does not produce exact answer, if you convert again to string it gives original answer

Comment: "but I can't figure exact time rather than original date" there was no time on the NSString, so it puts midnight by default. But since I guess you are in India with a 5:30 from GMT, this explains the 18:30.

Comment: @Larme same problem

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in this line `[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMM YYYY"];`.

This `yyyy` specifies the calendar year whereas `YYYY` specifies the year (Week of Year). So you should use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.
So your code will be like this

`[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMM yyyy"];`

Comment: Why this downvote  ?

Comment: i am not assign the downvote

Comment: I don't see the reason to downvote here.

Comment: random person did this